# Converting StructType to Avro Schema, returns type as Union when using databricks spark-avro

Tags: apache-spark-sql, schema, avro, databricks, spark-avro

I am using databricks spark-avro to convert a dataframe schema into avro schema.The returned avro schema fails to have a default value. This is causing issues when i am trying to create a Generic record out of the schema. Can, any one help with the right way of using this function ?

```
Dataset<Row> sellableDs = sparkSession.sql("sql query");
SchemaBuilder.RecordBuilder<Schema> rb = SchemaBuilder.record("testrecord").namespace("test_namespace");
Schema sc = SchemaConverters.convertStructToAvro(sellableDs.schema(), rb, "test_namespace");
System.out.println(sc.toString());
System.out.println(sc.getFields().get(0).toString());
String schemaString = sc.toString();
sellableDs.foreach(
    (ForeachFunction<Row>) row -> {
        Schema scEx = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaString);
        GenericRecord gr;
        gr = new GenericData.Record(scEx);
        System.out.println("Generic record Created");
        int fieldSize = scEx.getFields().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldSize; i++ ) {
            // System.out.println( row.get(i).toString());
            System.out.println("field: " + scEx.getFields().get(i).toString() + "::" + "value:" + row.get(i));
            gr.put(scEx.getFields().get(i).toString(), row.get(i));
            //i++;
        }
    }
);
```

This is the df schema:

```
StructType(StructField(key,IntegerType,true), StructField(value,DoubleType,true))
```

This is the avro converted schema:

```
{"type":"record","name":"testrecord","namespace":"test_namespace","fields":[{"name":"key","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"value","type":["double","null"]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that the class [SchemaConverters](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/SchemaConverters.scala) does not include default values as part of the schema creation. You have 2 options, modify the schema adding default values before Record creation or filling the record before building with some value( it could be actually values from your row). For example null. This is an example how create a Record using your schema

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecordBuilder 
import org.apache.avro.Schema
var schema = new Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"testrecord\",\"namespace\":\"test_namespace\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"key\",\"type\":[\"int\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":[\"double\",\"null\"]}]}")


var  builder = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema);

for (i <- 0 to schema.getFields().size() - 1 ) {
  builder.set(schema.getFields().get(i).name(), null)
}

var record = builder.build();
print(record.toString())
```

Comment: thanks for the input. I was making mistaking by converting the schema field to string instead of inferring the name. Thanks for the help